# alpha texture madness

Tags: transparency

Blender 2.79

windows 8.1 x64

I have made an earth with a few textures.  Then I place a slightly larger sphere around the earth, and put clouds on it.
When I turn on the alpha channel of this larger cloud sphere, there are very bad artifacts in the 3d view.
1) the spot where the specular highlight should appear on the earth is completely erased
2) The area around the clouds is very blocky and bad, sometimes punching holes in the earth behind mesh under it.

[image: Alpha Madness]

I am attaching the .blend.

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: transparency in the 3d viewport always wasn't something reliable, just as material shading as well, it's approximation. While it was improved and mostly works in Cycles 2.79 there still might be some unexpected behaviour while previewing in material shading mode

Comment: Its worth noting, this does not affect the render at all. It will render as it is supposed to, it is just the viewport that has this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's known problem in blender. And BF working with it. Look how this will be look like in 2.8, in Eevee:

[image]

But now. You can switch render engene to Blender Game, and change Alpha Blend type to Alpha Anti-aliasing:

[image]

It looks better.

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea, when I switch to "rendered" viewport, everything turns black and white?

Comment: Some of the textures also appear to warp in render.

Comment: @TagNelson **Resive transparent shadows** not enabled

Comment: thanks, and I also figured out the warped textures.